# Check for Substring in Dictionary as an if condition

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

I am working with a set of data that looks like a series of nested dictionaries. 
Here is an example:

```
{
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler/playlists",
    "items": [
        {
            "collaborative": false,
            "external_urls": {
                "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/user/wizzler/playlists/53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler/playlists/53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c",
            "id": "53Y8wT46QIMz5H4WQ8O22c",
            "images": [],
            "name": "Wizzlers Big Playlist",
            "owner": {
                "external_urls": {
                    "spotify": "http://open.spotify.com/user/wizzler"
                },
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler",
                "id": "wizzler",
                "type": "user",
                "uri": "spotify:user:wizzler"
            },
            "public": true,
            "snapshot_id": "bNLWdmhh+HDsbHzhckXeDC0uyKyg4FjPI/KEsKjAE526usnz2LxwgyBoMShVL+z+",
            "tracks": ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I have no issue calling any values that I want from this dataset. However, I am trying to perform a function on only dict items that contain the word "EDM." Currently with my code when I run it it performs the function on none of the playlists despite many containing "EDM".

Here is a snippet of code.

```
for items in results['items'] and results2['items']:
    if(userid == items['owner']['id'] 
       and items['tracks']['total'] >= intposition 
       and "EDM" in str(items['name'])):
        sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(items['owner']['id'],items['id'], tracks, position)
        print("added to" + items['owner']['display_name'] 
              + " s list  " + items['name'])
```

Hopefully I provided enough info and formatted this decently.

Comment: could you provide an example of a dictionary with one of the items containing `EDM` ? Also why do you do `for items in results['items'] and results2['items']:` if it's the same as `for items in results['items']:`?

Comment: That data is in what is known as [JSON](https://www.json.org) format.

Comment: shoule `items['owner']` be `items[0]['owner']`?

Comment: What do you think `for items in results['items'] and results2['items']:` does (because it doesn't make sense plus you haven't described what `results2` is).

Comment: Guys I am stupid... my current code is working. BTW results2 is a query of a spotify user's playlists that returns JSON as its results. the query can only grab 50 playlists at a time so I have a counter that if it reaches 50 it starts a new query with an offset of 50